# Pandas/Python dtype that mimics NCHAR(X)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fixed-width

I want to read an Excel and pass DTYPES like CHAR(X) to tell the column that fill the rest with spaces, to create a txt fixed width(in which every column has a different width).

I'm doing this right now.

```
dictp7 = {
    "Tipo Registro": np.dtype("str"),
    "Tipo Registro 2": np.dtype("str")}

df = pd.read_excel("lote.xlsx", dtype=dictp7)

df["Tipo Registro"] = df["Tipo Registro"].astype("string").str.rjust(11, " ")
df["Tipo Registro 2"] = df["Tipo Registro 2"].astype("string").str.rjust(160, " ")
open("lote.txt", "w").write(df.to_string(header=False))
```

(this is the short version)
I do this for each column, it works.

but maybe there is a better solution, that takes directly from the specified dtypes?

In know that doesn't work, but something like:

```
dictp7 = {
    "Tipo Registro": str.rjust(11)}
```

would be good

and this:

```
dictp7 = {
    "Tipo Registro": str.rjust(11).fillna(' ' * 11)}
```

would be amazing.

WHY YOU WANT TO DO THIS?
well, because this file has to be presented in a specific fixed width format(and each column is a different width) for the process to work.
No, I can not change the way this process works. I can only follow guidelines.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve?  I can't imagine that you actually want to modify how this data is stored, but if you're trying to tweak the DISPLAY of the data (which is reasonable), `pandas` can do that with `.set_properties`.  You can set several CSS-like properties, like `text-align`.

Comment: .set_properties doesn't let me specify the exact width of each column.

Comment: You can trim the columns to N spaces using the code you have, and use `set_properties` to set right alignment.  If you need exact formatting, then you may not be able to rely totally on panda's general formatting rules.  They're designed to look good, but not to adhere to rigid strictures.

Comment: yes, i would need something like "to_fwf", but meh, sticking to my janky code for now

Comment: It's hard to argue with "it works".